# Laravel POST via Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to submit a form via ajax, but I'm always getting internal server error

Here is my form code

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'users.add', 'id'=>'form']) !!}
<!-- Solo moderador -->
<div class="card-panel">
    @if(Auth::user()->permision->request == 1)
        <p class="center">Observaciones del moderador:</p>
        <textarea type="textarea" class="materialize-textarea" name="observations" id="updateObservations"></textarea> 
    @else
        <div class="center">
            <input type="checkbox" id="userVerify" class="filled-in">
            <label for="userVerify">Problema solucionado :)</label>
        </div> 
    </div>
    @endif 
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Here is my route

```
Route::post('request/update', 'RequestsController@postUpdateRequest')->name('request.update');
```

Here is my Ajax method

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    dataType: "html",
    url: 'request/update',
    data: $("#form").serialize(),
    success: function (response) {
        // write here any code needed for handling success         
        console.log("se envio");
    }
});
```

and here is my method in the controller

```
public function postUpdateRequest(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax())
    {
        // Obteniendo registro de la petición
        $petition = Petition::where('id', $request->id)->first();

        // Guardando
        $petition->fill($request->all());
        $auditConfirm = $petition->isDirty();
        $petition->save();

        // Guardando registro de auditoría
        if($auditConfirm){
            AuditsController::postAudit($this->action_id_update);
        }
    }

}
```

EDIT: [This is the console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThD42.png)

Comment: Probably not the answer to your question, but you also seem to have a misplaced `</div>` in the first provided code block. Check the ones before the `@endif`

Comment: Thanks! i will check it out

Comment: Please do not add SOLVED in title, if you like add your solution as an answer *"SOLVED:it seems that ive been missing the id value in the request all this time"*, even if this maybe is better of being closed as typo

Comment: Ok sorry, gotcha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include this in your form:

```
 echo Form::token();
```

Basically Laravel expects a CSRF token, middleware makes sure that token sent from form matches the token created before it.

If you don't want to add that on forum, you can add that in AJAX setup:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

..and have this in the HTML page header:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Comment: I already have it in my code, I added it a few days ago, the GET method does not give me any problems but for some reason POST gives me that error ..

Comment: i edited my post with a picture of the console output

Comment: Please have a look at storage/logs/laravel.log it will give an indication of what's wrong, if possible post the logs too.

Comment: [2017-07-16 21:35:54] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to a member function fill() on null' in C:\xampp\htdocs\fixnet\app\Http\Controllers\Backend\RequestsController.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 {main}

Comment: Do ``\Log::info($petition);``

Comment: I solved it! it seems that i missed the id value in the request.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) token, Laravel has a method of handling this vulnerability via [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-introduction), you have 2 options:

1. Add csrf token in html form:

`{!! Form::open(['route' => 'users.add', 'id'=>'form']) !!}
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="csrf-token" value="{{ Session::token() }}" />`

2. Provide a global header when making a request:

   `$.ajaxSetup({
       headers: {
           'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
       }
   });`

Read [more](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token)

Comment: I already have the .ajaxSetup... i forgot to add it in the question

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:it seems that ive been missing the id value in the request all this time